# Can i use wildcards to define a resource in an AWS IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Im specifying a role in CloudFormation but need to be able to access multiple resources.  So for example i may have 5 repos named myrepos1, myrepos2 etc...

Can i use a wildcard for this so that i catch them all in a single line?

```
{
        "Action": [
          "codecommit:GetFolder",
          "codecommit:GetFile",
          "codecommit:GetDifferences",
          "codecommit:GetBlob"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:827716541031:myrepos*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Though you should be careful because you would also allow access to another repo called `myreposupersecretsensitivestuff` if it existed.

Comment: Thats great.  But how?  I have tried the above for a codecommit trigger to start a lambda.  If the repo is called myrepos it works.  It its called myreposwhatever it does not work.  Is there some syntax im missing?

Comment: You are confusing the IAM permissions/policy and the CodeCommit trigger. What are you trying to trigger from code commit?

Comment: I absolutely was confusing the function policy and the execution role.  I added a * to the execution role and it works fine.  

User error im afraid